# github actions: buildx call failed with gradle and docker-push actions

Tags: docker, gradle, github-actions, ktor

I'm building a web server with gradle and would like to push it to docker using github actions.

my workflow:

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  main:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 1.8
        uses: actions/setup-java@v1
        with:
          java-version: 1.8
      - name: Make gradlew executable
        run: chmod +x ./gradlew
      - name: Build with Gradle
        run: ./gradlew build
      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1
      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1 
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build and push
        id: docker_build
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: repo/web-server
          build-args: |
            arg1=value1
            arg2=value2
      - name: Image digest
```

run: echo ${{ steps.docker_build.outputs.digest }}

Dockerfile:

```
# We select the base image from. Locally available or from https://hub.docker.com/
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

# We define the user we will use in this instance to prevent using root that even in a container, can be a security risk.
ENV APPLICATION_USER ktor

# Then we add the user, create the /app folder and give permissions to our user.
RUN adduser -D -g '' $APPLICATION_USER
RUN mkdir /app
RUN chown -R $APPLICATION_USER /app

# Marks this container to use the specified $APPLICATION_USER
USER $APPLICATION_USER

# We copy the FAT Jar we built into the /app folder and sets that folder as the working directory.
COPY ./app/build/libs/app-0.0.1.jar /app/my-application.jar
WORKDIR /app

# We launch java to execute the jar, with good defauls intended for containers.
CMD ["java", "-server", "-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions", "-XX:+UseCGroupMemoryLimitForHeap", "-XX:InitialRAMFraction=2", "-XX:MinRAMFraction=2", "-XX:MaxRAMFraction=2", "-XX:+UseG1GC", "-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100", "-XX:+UseStringDeduplication", "-jar", "my-application.jar"]
```

Exception:

```
Error: buildx call failed with: error: failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to compute cache key: failed to walk /tmp/buildkit-mount311472191/app/build/libs: lstat /tmp/buildkit-mount311472191/app/build/libs: no such file or directory
```